# need to update values inside an object using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, mongoose

this is my model.Here i am receiving an object from the server called response. Now i need to update the data base with this response object.
But the problem is i can only update the variables but not the objects like father.
Father is one object now i need to update father's firstname. But its giving me error if i use Father.Firstname saying unexpected token.
please help me out how to overcome this problem..

```
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

function createStudent(response) {
  console.log(response);
    var list = new User({
        Firstname : response.Fname,
        Age : response.age,
        Lastname : response.Lname,
        Father.Firstname : response.fatherfname,
        Father.Lastname : response.fatherlname,
        Father.Occupation : response.occupation,
        Father.PlaceOfWork : response.placeofwork,
        Father.OfficialAddress : response.officaladd,
        Father.EmailId : response.emailid,
        Father.PhoneNo : response.phoneno,
        Father.MobileNo : response.mobileno,


    });
    list.save();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use the `dot(.)` character in you object key names then you need to enclose it withing `double("")` or `single('')` quotes like you do with strings.

So write your code like this -

```
"Father.Firstname" : response.fatherfname,
```

instead of

```
Father.Firstname : response.fatherfname,
```

Comment: yeah i thought it won't work at first. Thank you so much